# Como le fue - cual es el objeto indirecto

Tags: pronombres

"Como le fue" - how did it go. 
Why is the indirect object pronoun (le) used?
Is this one of those language "idioms" or expressions, that just have to be learned, or is there a grammar-based reason here?

Answer (score 2):

"¿Cómo le fue?"

can be translated as but does not strictly mean:

"How did it go?"

because in the Spanish question there is an indirect object "le" (for you/him/her) which is not present in the English question, which can thus be interpreted as a general question, not involving anybody in particular (how did things go?):

In:

- ¿Cómo le fue?

the subject is impersonal and "le" is used to mean "for you" (usted) or "for him/her" (él/ella):

- How did things go **for you/him/her**? (¿Cómo **le** fue?)

Answer (score 0):

Puede actuar como saludo a modo de pregunta, o como una pregunta independiente.

"Como **le** fue" (**a usted**, en sus actividades) ("Como **te** fue" ( en tus actividades)). ¿Bien?, ¿Mal?, ¿Regular?. ¿Cómo va el día?

- ¿Cómo **le** fue a **él**? (en general en sus actividades) ¿Bien?, ¿Mal?, ¿Regular? ¿Cómo **le** va el día (a él)?
- ¿Cómo **le** fue a **ella**? (en general en sus actividades) ¿Bien?, ¿Mal?, ¿Regular? ¿Cómo **le** va el día (a ella)?

**le** esta refiriéndose **a él** a **a ella** o **a usted**

**le** sustituye **a él** a **a ella** o **a usted**

Podemos utilizar un truco para verlo más claro. *Si el Complemento Indirecto (CI) lo ponemos delante del verbo lo que hace el español es repetirlo de manera pronominal con **le / les*** (existiría duplicación).

- ¿**A él** **le** fue bien, mal, regular en sus actividades?
- ¿**A ella** **le** fue (bien, mal, regular en sus actividades)?
- ¿**A usted** **le** fue (bien, mal, regular en sus actividades)?

**Preguntamos,** ***¿A quien le fue Bien, Mal, Regular, en sus actividades?***

- **A él** / **A ella** / **A usted (a ti)** como Complemento Indirecto (CI)

---

- ¿A **él** cómo **le** fue?. - (¿(A él) como **le** fue?) - (¿ Cómo **le** fue?)
- ¿A **ella** cómo **le** fue?. (¿(A ella) como **le** fue?) - (¿ Cómo **le** fue?)
- ¿A **usted** (ti) cómo **le** (te) fue?. (¿(A usted) como **le** fue?) - (¿ Cómo **le** fue?)